import latest version of git hosted dbt package
We host a common dbt repo with centralised documentation on our gitlab server. We noticed that other dbt repos do not automatically import the latest package version (running dbt deps). Only by adding a revision specification with a commit SHA ensures that the specified version gets imported:
packages:
  - git: https://{{env_var('DBT_USER_NAME')}}:{{env_var('DBT_ENV_SECRET_DEPLOY_TOKEN')}}@gitlab/.../repo.git
    revision: b27fdf43580348fead84652124438e0f53fd6623

It is also possible to specify a branch:
revision: main

However, I noticed that it does not ensure that it always imports the latest version. Apparently, it gets cached. Running git clean does not solve the problem.
How could I enforce this without having to manually update commit hashes?
